# Knowing which memory pages were Accessed during execution

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, pthreads

In my program, I need to know which pages are being accessed by the program periodically, So after each 0.5 or 1 second I check which pages were accessed and calculate a checksum from those page values.

I use `mprotect` function to mark memory areas which need to be seen and install `SIGSEGV` signal handler for each thread. During start of each period, I set the protection to `PROT_READ` and then when a page fault occurs, I give both read and write access to the page after noting its address.

However, I notice that this method makes the execution of my program pretty slow. Also since I am doing it for each thread, it further degrades the performance. Is there any way to make this procedure faster. Especially, is it possible to make this at process level, so for example if Thread A induces a page fault, it gives write to that page and when Thread B accesses it, it already has write permissions.

Comment: Is mprotect really thread specific? Threads share the same address space

Comment: mprotect is not, but SIGSEGV is.

Comment: I was just referring to last sentence.

Comment: Yes, yi_H, SIGSEGV is thread specific. I was refering to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For faster method, the special compiler pass can be constructed. It will instrument memory access with changing a flag in the shadow memory. E.g. for each read or write operation, the compiler pass will add special write operation to some thread-specific area (shadow memory).

There is a http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/ project, which works as additional pass to LLVM compiler. The additional memory (shadow memory) is 8 time less then used memory. AddressSanitizer uses this pass to detect accesses to uninitialized memory: http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizerAlgorithm The slowdown is only 1.5x-3x.
For page grained flagging, the shadow memory will be very small (1-4 bytes of shadow for 4096 bytes of usual memory).

If you don't want to do this at compiler or can't do this (e.g. closed-source applications), you can use the existing COW technique from the kernel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write Kernel does COW for each fork via memory access flags. You can fork a process at time t1, stop the child, wait 1 or 2 seconds and then compare mappings of stopped child (it has no writes, so the mapping is the same as it was at t1) and of your process (changed pages are remapped). This variant is faster, but it gives info only about writes and not about each thread actions.

Also, you can hack the COW page fault handler in kernel. This hack will be harder, but it will have information about which thread did a write.

Comment: The fork option that you mentioned is good, but it doesn't solve my problem, because my problem is exactly the opposite, that is I'm trying to see diversion of two replicated processes, so I can't rely on the fact that two of them will execute similarly.

Comment: @MetallicPriest, please, invite me to other questions. The google alerts, installed for them is so slooow (7 minutes for this question). I have some doubts about forking a multithreaded process, some memory mappings could be freeed at such fork. But the idea is - kernel already does such accounting of changed pages.

Comment: What is fork-relations for two replicated processes? Are they forked from one parent; or they are restored by you from checkpoint? If there was a common parent, the COW mappings will show you the pages, writted by both replicas.

Comment: How do one invite other users by the way. Since I'm relatively new to Stackoverflow, I don't know how to :)!

Comment: Well, actually both. Initially I fork a process to be the replica, check the pages of them periodically to know of any diversion and take a checkpoint by forking the original process. I used Solaris that has forkall function available.

Comment: I have one more idea, which is that when a page fault occurs, I also give write access to neighbouring pages since it is expected that neighbouring pages will be accessed soon next. I think that way I will achieve some performance gain.

Comment: The COW is used in Solaris too. You can get the information from list of corresponding virtual pages and physical pages.

Comment: I read one paper which uses Translation look aside buffer misses to note down the pages. Do you have any idea how we can have access to the TLB?

Comment: TLB misses are like a puzzle for me. This is because I think (I'm not universally true here, there are PA-RISC, poor SparcsV9, MIPS, poor Itanium and some other) that hardware may refill TLB without any software help (the format of page table is fixed; address of PageTable Root is stored in special register; Page Table is kept up-to-date by OS). There is no software TLB miss handler; the only handler here is page fault handler.

Comment: Citing one paper about such method: "Several modern RISC architectures (e.g., the MIPS R2000/3000, the DEC Alpha, and the HP PA-RISC) handle
TLB misses in software." This is not for x86.